# how to convert Int8 to Uint8 in swift?

Tags: ios, macos

```
var ss = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: 20)
var b:Data = Data.init(capacity: 20)

for i in 0...19{
    b[i] = UInt8(ss[i])
}
```

this sentence will not show error utill the ss[i] was bigger than 127.which was a negative number.then it shows an error. says it's not allowed to be a negative number.

how to solve it? I'm a newbie of swift.

Comment: This may be related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358288/how-to-cast-int8-to-uint8-in-swift

Answer (score -2):

var b:Data = Data(bytes:ss,count: 20)

Comment: Add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.